# AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

Tags: celery, python-3.5, python-multiprocessing

I am using celery 4.2.1 with python 3.5.
My multiprocessing code is below:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register(str("Conns"), ConnClass)
multiprocessing.freeze_support()

if __name__ == 'tasks':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    mana = MyManager()
    mana.start()
    glob = mana.Conns()
```

**This work on Ubuntu 16.04 but not working on WINDOWS 7. Getting below error**

mana.start()
File "c:\users\seshabhattar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\Lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 479, in start
self._process.start()

File "c:\users\seshabhattar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 103, in start

'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'

**AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children**

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar Error trying to call a multiprocessing function from a Celery task in django. I solved using billiard instead of multiprocessing

```
import billiard as multiprocessing
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah.Using billiard package worker does not share its memory with other workers but in multiprocessing he does. Its resolved the error but not solved the purpose.